# Can I continue using brave headers in spring boot 3 with micrometer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I started migrating to spring boot 3, and also spring-cloud-sleuth to micrometer (https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide#samples).

Added this dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    <version>${micrometer-tracing.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    <version>${micrometer-tracing.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is how can I still use the b3 headers ?

Before we were sending this headers:

```
x-b3-traceid:0c49e38ece42bef5
x-b3-spanid:0c49e38ece42bef5
```

Now from what I see we have to send this header(https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#trace-flags):

```
traceparent: 00-4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736-00f067aa0ba902b7-00
```

Is there additional config that needs to be done in order to use the headers as before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:
Use this bean

```
@Bean
public Tracing braveTracing() {
    return Tracing.newBuilder()
            .propagationFactory(B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder().injectFormat(B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE_NO_PARENT).build())
            .build();
}
```

or just add this in application.properties :

```
management.tracing.propagation.type=b3
```

Comment: `B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE_NO_PARENT` does not get old headers, you need to set it to  `B3Propagation.Format.MULTI`

Comment: @VíctorHerraiz I use the bean approach and it works for me with SINGLE_NO_PARENT. MULTI probably will generate both b3 and w3c.

Comment: https://javadoc.io/doc/io.zipkin.brave/brave/latest/brave/propagation/B3Propagation.Format.html MULTI uses `x-b3-` fields as requested in the query

Comment: It seems like another breaking change, I wonder if it is documented or not as indeed with sb 2.* it was MULTI

Comment: you can use MULTI or SINGLE_NO_PARENT depending on what you need.