# Use both B3 and W3C trace formats in trace propagation between Spring Boot 2 & 3 applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer-tracing

I am migrating from Spring Boot 2 to Spring boot 3, and switched from spring cloud sleuth to `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave` in the migration process. I noticed that Spring Boot 2 services use `b3` headers to propagate span & trace IDs, while the new Spring Boot 3 projects use a w3c `traceparent` header.

To still be able to trace messages through multiple Spring Boot 2 and Spring Boot 3 services *in our own domain*, I configured every Spring Boot 3 service in our domain to keep using the "old" B3 format using [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75543408/can-i-continue-using-brave-headers-in-spring-boot-3-with-micrometer):

```java
@Bean
public Tracing braveTracing() {
    return Tracing.newBuilder()
            .propagationFactory(B3Propagation.newFactoryBuilder().injectFormat(B3Propagation.Format.SINGLE).build())
            .build();
}
```

Which works, however I'd rather have the Spring Boot 3 applications recognize *both* formats and (if possible) propagate both formats as well. The reason is that applications *outside our domain* expect the W3C header instead of the B3 header. Would anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to use multiple tracing header types by **removing** the `Tracing` bean I configured in my original post, and by setting the consume and produce properties in the application.yml:

```yaml
management:
  tracing:
    propagation:
      consume: [b3, w3c]
      produce: [b3, w3c]
      # type: [b3, w3c] if consume and produce are the same, type can be used as well
```

Three propagation types can be used:

- b3 to use the concatenated `b3: {TraceId}-{SpanId}-{SamplingState}-{ParentSpanId}` header
- b3_multi to use separate headers such as `X-B3-SpanId` and `X-B3-TraceId`
- w3c to use the `traceparent` header

More info regarding the trace headers can be found [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/b3-propagation).

Be sure to add the `@AutoConfigureObservability` annotation to SpringBootTests if you plan to test the tracing setup in your application. Also, ensure the RestTemplate bean is constructed using an injected RestTemplateBuilder instead of using `new RestTemplate()`, as the builder adds tracing configuration by default.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says it is not possible :

> Since the default propagation format is w3c and **in Spring Boot 3.0 we don't support multiple propagation types**, you should set in your Sleuth & Boot 2.x application spring.sleuth.propagation.type=w3c,b3 so that you publish the headers in 2 formats. One for the current Boot 2.x applications (b3) and one for the new Boot 3.x applications (w3c).

[Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide#context-propagation)

In our case, we added a custom interceptor over our OkHttpClient to propagate both formats.